# Update table on the base of other table with php and oracle

Tags: php, database, oracle

I want to update table with unique result after searching the records one by one form other table on the base of House number.
Example:
I have one table named "Complaint Point" that have two columns "House No" and  "Status"
Other table named "Complaint Table" that have also two columns "House No" and  "Status" but there are multiple entries of same House No.
I wanted to compare each house number and status from table "Complaint Table",if any status present "OPEN" then it's update second table "Complaint Point" column status also "OPEN" and if all the status present "CLOSED in table "Complaint Table" then i update the first table "Complaint Point" column status "CLOSED".

I want this using the php and oracle.

I am doing this:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) == "Save")
{

    $STATUS = $_POST['COMPLAINT_STATUS'];
    $HOUSE_NO = $_POST['COMPLAINT_HOUSE_NO'];
$query ="SELECT STATUS FROM complainttable WHERE HOUSE_NO = '" . $_POST["COMPLAINT_HOUSE_NO"] . "' AND STATUS = 'CLOSED' ";
    $results = ociparse($conn, $query);
    ociexecute($results);
    while($row=oci_fetch_assoc($results)) {

    echo '<option>' . $row['STATUS'] . '</option>';

    if (isset($_POST['STATUS']) == "CLOSED")
    {
    $update = "UPDATE complaintpoint SET STATUS= 'CLOSED' where HOUSE_NO ='" . $_POST["HOUSE_NO"] . "' ";

    $send = oci_parse($conn, $update);
    oci_bind_by_name($send, ':STATUS', $STATUS);
    oci_execute($send);
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<option value="">Complaint is Still Open</option>';   
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will update

If any **housenumber** is **OPEN** in **complaintTable** then SET **status=OPEN** of that house number in **complaintpoint** table

```
     $query   =  "SELECT * FROM complainttable WHERE STATUS = 'OPEN' ";
     $results = ociparse($conn, $query);
     ociexecute($results);
        while($row=oci_fetch_assoc($results)) 
        {

                $update = "UPDATE complaintpoint SET STATUS= 'OPEN' where HOUSE_NO ='" . $row["HOUSE_NO"] . "' ";
                $send = oci_parse($conn, $update);
                oci_bind_by_name($send, ':STATUS', $STATUS);
                oci_execute($send);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay,your answer is just informaing me housenumber is OPEN in complaintTable then SET status=OPEN of that house number in complaintpoint table.My question is that to compare each house number and status from one table,if any status present "OPEN" then it's update other table status  "OPEN" and if all the status present "CLOSED in one table,it's update the other table status CLOSED.

Comment: Yes the above code server the purpose.

If any housenumber is OPEN in complaintTable then SET status=OPEN of that house number in complaintpoint table
say there are 4 housenumber 
001 - open,
001 - close,
002 - close,
002 - close

the first query will find 001-open only and set status to be open in complaintpoint of 001 as OPEN

Comment: Please any body help me.